# Double byte font checking in PDF using PDFBOX

Tags: validation, pdf, fonts, pdfbox

In my new application i am using PDFBox to validate a PDF document.
My requirement is to check if font used in a PDF is double byte or not.
I know in PDFBox there is an option to check whether the font is composite or not,but not sure how to do that.It would be really great if someone help me out in this topic.
Please refer the the sample pdf for the same.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzaBYVk1XnP_Y3M2d29Icllyam8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What do you actually want to check? The fact that a font is stored using a composite font mechanism or whether its language (that's a vague concept I know) is double-byte? In other words, are you attempting to detect languages such as Chinese or Japanese or attempting the detect the technical composite feature?

Comment: Thanks a lot David,I am more interested in checking if the font mechanism is composite in nature.

Comment: If I look at the documentation for pdfbox, it has PDFont class that has a member getSubType. If you create the PDFont from the CosDict object that represents it, wouldn't this give you the information you are looking for? If getSubType determines the font is a Type0 font, you know it's using the composite font mechanism...

Comment: Thanks.But one question?There are Type1 and Type2 font also.Those are not composite?Does compposite means double bytes?

Comment: Thanks David,I just followed the approach suggested by you and it solved my problem.Although i have another doubt do you have any idea whether LineArt validation can be supported by PDFBox?